# Sending a message to a remote broker using a pem-certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, pem

I'm writing a script to get some sensor-data using MQTT, transform the incoming value is a specific way and forward it to a cloud which uses an encrypted communication. 
The script runs on RaspberryPi 3 (Raspbian) where Mosquitto runs as MQTT-broker ( The sensors send the data to this broker)

So far I get the information from the the sensors and I can transform the content like desired.

The problem is when I try to connect to the remote broker, I got following error-message

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
at Error (native)
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:67:17)
at Object.TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1015:46)
at Object.buildBuilder (/home/pi/node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/tls.js:13:20)
at MqttClient.wrapper [as streamBuilder] (/home/pi/node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js:135:36)
at MqttClient._setupStream (/home/pi/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:246:22)
at new MqttClient (/home/pi/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:227:8)
at Object.connect (/home/pi/node_modules/mqtt/lib/connect/index.js:138:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/GATT_server/MQTT_module.js:3:25)
```

I have tried to configure Mosquitto as MQTT-bridge to use the config-file and it looks like it'd work (There are no error messages when the service is restarted).

The problem when I use Mosquitto as a bridge the script can't subscribe to the topics published by the sensors.

I'm not familiar with those certificates but from reading the doc of the file 'client-options.cs' I wrote following lines:

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost', 'port:1883');
var remoteBroker = mqtt.connect('mqtts://xxx.xxx.io', 
 {port:8883,
 protocol:'ssl', 
 username:'username', 
 password:'123password123', 
 cert:'/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.pem'} );
                
/*....
.... many lines later
....*/
remoteBroker.publish(topicToUseOnRemoteMqttBroker, PayloadToForward);
```

Am I doing it right? Or did I miss something?

If the certificate is OK for the Mosquitto-Bridge it should be OK for the remote broker, too. - Is that right?

If you have additional links/papers about this topic - I like to learn ;P
Google gave me so many information - I don't know where to start :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry for the `cert` should not be the path to the certificate file, but the actual cert it's self. You need to read the file in and pass that.

Somethings like this:

```
var remoteBroker = mqtt.connect('mqtts://xxx.xxx.io', 
    {port:8883,
    protocol: 'ssl', 
    username: 'username', 
    password: '123password123', 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.pem')} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. And now I see the solution it very clear why. :lol: Thank you again